# Как сделать чтобы был метод get

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

```
<div id='count'></div>
<iframe></iframe>
<script>
var url = "http://kc.areawars.ru/hunt_conf.php";
var params = {"mode":"farm", "action": "chek", "num":21};
var i = 0;
var scan = setTimeout(function link() {
   params.num++;
   var queryArray = [];
   for (var key in params){
       queryArray.push(key+"=" + params[key]);
   }
   var query = url + '?' + queryArray.join("&");
   document.querySelector('iframe').src= query;
   i++;
   document.querySelector('#count').textContent = i;
   if(i < 100) setTimeout(link, 62000);
}, 63000);
</script>
```

Comment: Всё непонятно :(.

Comment: Цель - написание скрипта изменяющего параметры цифр в ссылке на число большее текущего на 1 и автоматически отправлял ее с интервалом 62 секунды

Comment: Но этот не работает нужно чтобы подставлялись значения методом get или post

Comment: Прочитайте про ajax

Comment: И переформулируйте вопрос что-бы было понятно и желательно откомментируйте код